# Is it possible to have a plural subject be a singular thing?

Tags: grammatical-number

Here's a sentence I don't particularly understand.

"Necessary goods such as **food** also had to be shipped in order to meet the dietary needs of a consolidated population."

Wouldn't it have to be instead, "Necessary goods such as **vegetables and meat products** also had to be shipped in order to meet the dietary needs of a consolidated population"?

Comment: "Such as" specifically introduces a single example. You can go on and list several examples, or even many, but one is perfectly sufficient. I like alcoholic beverages, such as beer. I have many hobbies, such as sailing. There are lots of really  weird questions on this site, such as this one. Additionally, "vegetables and meat products" does not cover all of "food". So not only is your rewording much longer than the original, it does not even mean the same thing.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thanks you answered my question. Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that the substitution of "vegetables and meat products" was simply an attempt to have multiple food items.  That isn't necessary.

Some style preferences would set off "such as food" with commas:

> Necessary goods, such as food, also had to be shipped...

It's descriptive information about "goods".  You could even remove it without changing the meaning of the sentence:

> Necessary goods also had to be shipped...

That's the meat and purpose of the sentence -- to talk about the fact that necessary goods had to be shipped.

"Necessary goods such as what?", you might ask.  What you think is necessary might be very different from what I think is necessary.  So it's helpful to have some kind of example for context.

The reader doesn't need a complete manifest.  We don't even want more examples than necessary because that would distract from the point of the sentence, getting bogged down in tangential details.

In this case, perhaps food epitomizes the goods.  Everybody knows how necessary food is, so that one example clarifies the nature of what the author means by "necessary".  The author doesn't need to include other examples just because "goods" is plural; it's plural because it refers to the many different items that were shipped.  So adding just that one example:

> Necessary goods, such as food, also had to be shipped...

Leave out the optional commas, and that's your sentence.